# Laravel for each loop makes extra list

Tags: php, laravel

I'm kind of banging my head cause can't get what went wrong with the loop. Im looping each user to find matching classwork with submissions. There are total of 4 classworks made. The user i'm currently looping has made 2 submissions to each respective classwork. The other users have no submissions made. I cant find what made the other extra 4 tags.

[image]

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center font-w600 mb-2">
    <span style="width:50px">#{{$loop->index +1}}</span>
    <span style="width:500px">{{$user->name}}</span>
    @foreach($classworks as $classwork)
        @forelse($user->submission as $submission)
            @if($submission->classwork->title == $classwork->title)
                <a href="/classwork/{{$classwork->id}}/{{$submission->id}}">
                    <span class="badge badge-pill p-2 mr-2
                    ">{{$submission->classwork->title}}</span>                            
                </a>
            @else
                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger p-2 mr-2">{{$classwork->title}}</span>
            @endif
        @empty
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger p-2 mr-2">{{$classwork->title}}</span>
        @endforelse
    @endforeach
</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You are outputing a span to each user submission, so you have 4 tags + 4 submissions equals to 8 tags.
You must output 1 span to each classwork, so you need remove output from the user submission loop and just place it into classwork loop. Like this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center font-w600 mb-2">
    <span style="width:50px">#{{$loop->index +1}}</span>
    <span style="width:500px">{{$user->name}}</span>

    @foreach($classworks as $classwork)
        <?php $found = false;?>
 
        @foreach($user->submission as $submission)
            @if($submission->classwork->title == $classwork->title)
                <?php $found = $submission->id; break;?>
            @endif
        @endforeach

        @if($found)
            <a href="/classwork/{{$classwork->id}}/{{$found}}">
               <span class="badge badge-pill p-2 mr-2
               ">{{$classwork->title}}</span>                            
            </a>
        @else
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger p-2 mr-2">{{$classwork->title}}</span>
        @endif

    @endforeach
</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center font-w600 mb-2">
    <span style="width:50px">#{{$loop->index +1}}</span>
    <span style="width:500px">{{$user->name}}</span>
    @foreach($classworks as $classwork)
        @forelse($user->submission as $submission)
            @if($submission->classwork->title == $classwork->title)
                <a href="/classwork/{{$classwork->id}}/{{$submission->id}}">
                    <span class="badge badge-pill p-2 mr-2
                    ">{{$submission->classwork->title}}</span>                            
                </a>
            @else
                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger p-2 mr-2">{{$classwork->title}}</span>
            @endif
        @empty
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger p-2 mr-2">{{$classwork->title}}</span>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</li>

@endforeach
```

try this one

Comment: it makes the same result.

Answer (score 0):

paste the loop below to your

tag because its repeat the li every time.